# Картинка поверх ссылки

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне сделать чтобы ссылки были кликабельными, но при этом изображение было поверх ссылок

```css
.flowers {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50px;
  &__block {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  }
  &__item {
    width: 200px;
    height: 129px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    &-title {
      font-family: "PT Sans";
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 18px;
      color: #03453b;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
    &.flower-6 {
      grid-column: 6;
      grid-row: 1 / span 2;
      height: 100%;
    }
    &:hover {
      box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
  }
  &__img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="flowers">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="flowers__block">
      <a href="#" class="flowers__item">
        <img class="flowers__item-img" src="img/flower-1.svg" alt="">
        <span class="flowers__item-title">Букеты</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="flowers__item">
        <img class="flowers__item-img" src="img/flower-2.svg" alt="">
        <span class="flowers__item-title">Монобукеты</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="flowers__item">
        <img class="flowers__item-img" src="img/flower-3.svg" alt="">
        <span class="flowers__item-title">Розы</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="flowers__item">
        <img class="flowers__item-img" src="img/flower-4.svg" alt="">
        <span class="flowers__item-title">Срезанные цветы</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="flowers__item">
        <img class="flowers__item-img" src="img/flower-5.svg" alt="">
        <span class="flowers__item-title">Свадебные букеты</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="flowers__item">
        <img class="flowers__item-img" src="img/flower-7.svg" alt="">
        <span class="flowers__item-title">Уличные растения</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="flowers__item">
        <img class="flowers__item-img" src="img/flower-8.svg" alt="">
        <span class="flowers__item-title">Подарки</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="flowers__item">
        <img class="flowers__item-img" src="img/flower-9.svg" alt="">
        <span class="flowers__item-title">Конфеты</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="flowers__item">
        <img class="flowers__item-img" src="img/flower-10.svg" alt="">
        <span class="flowers__item-title">Воздушные шары</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="flowers__item">
        <img class="flowers__item-img" src="img/flower-11.svg" alt="">
        <span class="flowers__item-title">Композиции</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="flowers__item flower-6">
        <img class="flowers__item-img" src="img/flower-6.svg" alt="">
        <span class="flowers__item-title">Комнатные растения</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img src="img/flowers-bg.png" alt="" class="flowers__img">
</section>
```

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса...

Comment: Есть картинка. Она находится поверх ссылки. Ссылка становится не кликабельна из-за картинки, как сделать чтобы ссылка была кликабельна, но чтобы при этом картинка была поверх ссылки?

Answer (score 2):

Возможно всё-таки прямоугольники ссылок должны быть прозрачными, а не фон должен лежать поверх ссылок. Подумайте над этим.

В вашем варианте с фоном сверху сделать ссылки кликабельными очень просто — используйте css свойство [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).

```css
.bg1, .bg2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

.bg1 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  left: 0px;
}

.bg2 {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  left: 100px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">click me click me click me click me</a>
<div class="bg1"></div>
<div class="bg2"></div>
```